# xsd.exe attribute order

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

My target is serialize c# classes to XML with attribute order like properties order in my classes. For this purporse I need add System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=int) before other property in my class.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("F4INVAL", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public F4invalType[] F4INVAL {
        get {
            return this.f4INVALField;
        }
        set {
            this.f4INVALField = value;
        }
    }
```

I have XSD-file ([f4form_2012_3.xsd](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62535368/f4form_2012_3.xsd)).

Using Xsd.exe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) I execute this scriptlet to generate a set of C# classes:

```
xsd f4form_2012_3.xsd /order /classes
```

I need to get class properties with C# attribute `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]`. And I do, but the first class' properties have this attribute.

The second and following classes don't have it.

Plase check [f4form_2012_3.cs](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62535368/f4form_2012_3.cs)

What does it mean?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What is your objective? You need to generate XML from classes or classes from XML?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici He wants to generate classes from XSD, so he can map a XML instance to CLR objects.

Comment: I mean serialization process: XSD -> generate CLR C# Class -> serialize object to XML.  Order of XML-attributes must be equals order of C# class properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `F4ReportType` complex type is the only type in your XSD that uses a `xsd:sequence` of elements. You cannot order properties generated from XML attributes, as attributes are not ordered in XML. Maybe you want to use XML elements instead.

Comment: You are right, for example the class `F4inf1Type` also has order attributes.

Comment: I mean serialization process: XSD -> generate CLR C# Class -> serialize object to XML. Order of XML-attributes must be equals order of C# class properties. – Peter Barbanyaga 18 mins ago